# How to identify updated/created rows in Oracle when DATE_MODIFIED is null

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The need to identify the updated rows in Oracle when date_modified column has null values and then update with date value in data_modified. Filled data_modified column is useful in next steps in our scenario.

The source system is not updating/inserting date_modified value even when the creation/update is happened.

Input data:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

I have an option to fill current date when null else leave as it is in date_modified col.
but the difficulty here is, my approach will always fill current date even if the rows updated or not.

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(MOD_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY'),to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')) FROM ORA.TABLE
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect results? I think your query might work.

Comment: Your query might be worked https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ceffa89ba461f08f8ca50a00ee4e0c92

Comment: My query works but my concern is, I am filling all the time with current date even if the row is changed or not. Not sure if my approach is correct or not. I have added sample data for better reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an adjustment of your query, but the way you describe the problem seems like a good place to use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <your_table>_MOD_TIME
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON <your_table>
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.mod_date IS NULL THEN
    :new.mod_date := SYSDATE;
  END IF;
END;
```

you could also add a separate column to store the action I or U for insert/update and this will give you better insight over what happened since this is good debug information and I don't think the overhead will be worth it.